# When cloning a hard drive, does the new hard drive have to be the same model as the older one?

Tags: hard-drive, clonezilla, cloning

I have a Samsung HD103SJ that's making weird noises when reading and I'd like to replace it. I'ts old, and this HDD costs around $130 on Amazon. I'd rather clone it to a Western Digital Black HDD, which costs $74 on Amazon, however I'm not sure if the hardware have to be exactly the same for a successful cloning.

If both HDDs are the same size (1TB), does the the HDDs brand and model have to be the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hard-drive doesn't need to be the same make or model but the new drive does have to be the same size or larger.

Comment: Some cloning software's will clone to a smaller drive.